# WinRT - SnapsToDevicePixels?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, windows-runtime

I can't find the SnapsToDevicePixels in the WinRT (.NET 4.5) framework for Windows 8.

How come? Was it removed? Are there any other alternatives to decrease bluriness in Windows 8 Metro applications?

Comment: I think the intended way to get rid of blurriness on Windows 8 Modern UI is to get high-DPI screens. After all they force the blurry fonts on all Modern apps and there's no fix for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest property within the WinRT profile is [UseLayoutRounding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.uselayoutrounding.aspx)

Since this answer was accepted, and I cannot delete the answer and the fact the original revision wasn't correct, I have simply modified the answer.

Comment: Ah, so it was just moved instead. Thanks.

Comment: What you linked to is about WPF in .Net 4.5. The question is about WinRT, which is completely different.

Comment: Svick, you are wrong. What he linked to is also included in WinRT. Notice the BitmapCache object. That's where it has been moved to, instead of the original object.

Comment: @MathiasLykkegaardLorenzen, notice the namespace. Everything from WinRT is in the Windows.* namespace.

Comment: Mathias, although `BitmapCache` is also available in WinRT, it does not have the `SnapToDevicesPixels` property, so it looks like svick is correct to point out that this answer is not useful in WinRT.

Answer (score 6):

Also see [`UseLayoutRounding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.uselayoutrounding.aspx). This can get rid of blurriness on images as well.

Comment: Just as with the other answer, what you are talking about is in WPF. The question is about WinRT.

Comment: Hmmm. I had assumed that was the WinRT documentation. Does it actually exist anywhere?

Comment: [It does.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211377.aspx) Note that the namespace is Windows.*, not System.Windows.*.

Comment: Thanks. Updated to point to the real documentation. Though interestingly it says the default is `true`.

Comment: Guys write that default value is false in blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/text/archive/2009/08/27/layout-rounding.aspx Not sure if it's a documentation bug or the article became obsolete.